# Is it possible to setup multiple urls for tomcat datasource

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection, connection-pooling

We have a backup database (which we want tomcat to failover in case primary database is down).

Trying to setup as following, but it is not working, am I missing something ?

```
<Resource auth="Container"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
          initialSize="5"
          maxIdle="10"
          maxTotal="15"
          maxWaitMillis="15000"
          name="jdbc/dbcporacle"
          username="username"
          password="xxxxxxxx"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbhost11111.com:3203/dbsvc111, jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbhost22222.com:3203/dbsvc111"/>
```

Note **2 urls** (comma separated) in the url attribute

Comment: You could have 2 datasources, and have a heartbeat ping with your database, if it's down, you could programatically change the datasource. I know that this is not what you're asking, but maybe it could help.

Comment: Yes, if the provider supports it. For example,  MySQL does.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not aware that there ever was such an option to provide two URLs and assume that they both have the same username/password. Where did you get this information? Or have you just been blindly trying?
2. Failing over to a different database is not as trivial as connecting to a different URL. Well, at first it is, but what happens when the original database comes back online? How does it get all the updates that were written to the secondary database? How will you determine that it's time to connect back to the original one?

One proper way to deal with failures is to configure your backend databases as cluster - they'll have a single URL that the application connects to, and transparently handle failover independently of your application.

So: Are you missing something? Yes: Configuring a datasource to two URLs never was supposed to work (let alone to work this way), and it won't solve your problem anyway.

And if your database is read-only, so that you *can* transparently switch between the alternatives: Handle this on the application level and just configure two databases that your application can failover to. This way your application will have to deal with it. Of course, you could implement your own DataSource to handle such a handover on failure of one of them.